# How to disable sessions in Yesod for a specific set of urls or a subsite?

Tags: session, haskell, yesod

I want to disable sessions for headless API endpoints, but I have to keep them turned on because this service also handles user logins.

However `makeSessionBackend` doesn't have access to `Handler` stuff or even current URI, like `isAuthorizedSource` does.

It appears to me that I should lift Client Session Backend code and sprinkle it with wrappers until the moment I can get at least textual path from that WAI `Request`.

Isn't there a better way to tell any bakend to ignore some routes like `StaticR`?

Answer (score 2):

All of your points can be modified by overriding the `makeSessionBackend` method in the Yesod typeclass. Something like

```
instance Yesod App where
    makeSessionBackend _ = fmap Just $ defaultClientSessionBackend expireTime filepath
      where expireTime = 24 * 60
```

Comment: I, too, expected something like this to work but found no way to access processed current route.